# C++ [&]() {...} construction

Tags: c++, c++11

In this [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) in code sample I have met an unfamiliar for me C++ code construction:

```
[&]() {/* code here*/}
```

It looks just like anonymous function or class in Java. Does anyone know what this construction means?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda function (an anonymous function that you can define inside another).

There's a pretty good SO post explaining it here.
[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since now I know that this is lambda I can see my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda function (C++11).